# Is Avogadro's constant equal to 1?

Tags: mole, notation, units

The mole is defined to be exactly $\mathrm{mol}=6.02214076\cdot 10^{23}$ entities. Avogadro's constant is defined as $N_A=6.02214076\cdot 10^{23}\mathrm{mol}^{-1}$.

Then why is it not usual to write
$$N_A=6.02214076\cdot 10^{23}\cdot (6.02214076\cdot 10^{23})^{-1}=1?$$

It doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: One mole of anything contains exactly 1.0 moles of that thing. Important as it is, this fact is somewhat too trivial to be stated more often.

Comment: @Ivan Neretin This is not the point of this question at all

Comment: It’s not a silly question, but what you’ve proven is precisely that: 1 mole of stuff has exactly 1 mole of stuff in it. In a way, we would probably be in trouble if it *wasn’t* 1.

Answer (score 3):

You have mixed up Avogadro number $N_0$ with Avogadro constant $N_\mathrm{A}$, and used the constant to define itself, which is incorrect mathematically. Analytical form of your suggestion is as follows:

$$N_\mathrm{A} = N_0\cdot\pu{mol^-1} \label{eqn:1}\tag{1}$$
$$\implies \pu{1 mol^-1} = N_\mathrm{A}\cdot N_0^{-1} \label{eqn:2}\tag{2}$$

Plugging \eqref{eqn:2} in \eqref{eqn:1} (even though it makes no sense mathematically) one gets

$$N_\mathrm{A} = N_0\cdot N_\mathrm{A}\cdot N_0^{-1}\tag{3}$$

Or, since both $N_0$ and $N_\mathrm{A}$ are non-zero by definition,

$$1 = 1\tag{4}$$

This is correct, but useless.

Comment: Please explain how I used the constant to define itself. The definitions I wrote were taken from Wikipedia (I changed "particles" to "entities", though).

Comment: And what you're doing here is very different from the thing in question. You use one equality only and substitute it into itself. Of course you get $1=1$. But I used two equalities. 1) $\mathrm{mol}=6.02214076\cdot 10^{23}$, 2) $N_A=6.02214076\cdot 10^{23}\,\mathrm{mol}^{-1}$. Taken together, they imply $N_A=1$.

Comment: There is a circular definition $\pu{mol}\to N_\mathrm{A}\to\pu{mol}.$ The quantities you are using in numerical form are, as I said, Avogadro number $N_0$ with Avogadro constant $N_\mathrm{A},$ correspondingly. You are "*taking them together*" against mathematical principles.

Comment: From Wikipedia: "The mole is defined as exactly $6.02214076\times 10^{23}$ particles." Also from Wikipedia: "Avogadro constant is defined as $6.02214076\times 10^{23}\,\mathrm{mol}^{-1}$." As you can see, there is no circularity involved. First, we defined mole, then we defined $N_A$.

Comment: You write $\mathrm{mol}\to N_A\to\mathrm{mol}$. That is not correct, as $N_A$ was *not* used in the definition of a mole. We defined mole just as a number of particles. And then we used $\mathrm{mol}$ to define $N_A$.

Comment: *Numerical value* of $N_\mathrm{A}$ is used in the definition of the mole, $N_0$ and $N_\mathrm{A}$ are inseparable entities, at least in context of current definition.

Comment: The number $6.02214076\cdot 10^{23}$ exists without any reference to the symbol $N_0$. We use $6.02214076\cdot 10^{23}$ to define $\mathrm{mol}$. *Then*, we define $N_0$ as $6.02214076\cdot 10^{23}$.

Comment: In other words, the number $6.02214076\cdot 10^{23}$ is defined purely in terms of mathematics.

Comment: This is not true. The number you for some reason return to all the time is "*is the fixed numerical value of the Avogadro constant*" ([SI Brochure](https://www.bipm.org/documents/20126/41483022/SI-Brochure-9-EN.pdf#page=20)). Look, let me ask you straight: don't you think it's strange that according to your proposition the same *constant* has two vastly different values, one which is dimensionless?

Comment: The constant has one and only one value. $N_A=6.02214076\cdot 10^{23}\,\mathrm{mol}^{-1}=1$. Indeed, the equality is correct if $\mathrm{mol}=6.02214076\cdot 10^{23}$. Nevertheless, I managed to find an article resolving this "apparent issue (my question)". https://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/acs.jchemed.9b00467 You may also find it interesting.